# Apache2.4 and Php-cgi : which chmod for log file?

Tags: apache-2.2, chmod

I'm using a Php lib (Monolog) to create my logs.

When I delete my log file and access my website in order to generate logs, I see the file created into the good log directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache    0 Nov 21 15:22 portal.log
```

But it's always empty (every request should be logged)... On the other hand the last modified date is updated every time it should generate logs.

I suspect a chmod problem, to fix it I tried a chmod 777 on the log file:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache    0 Nov 21 15:28 portal.log
```

But it doesn't fix the problem, same symptoms...

Did I miss something with chmod configuration?

Comment: Is the disk full?

Comment: I move my files in `/var/www/html` and now it works... The problem is solved but still ununderstanded

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your configuration is completely correct, if you truly believe it is a permission issue you'll need to ensure that all the folders leading up to `portal.log` are executable.

You can also test the file is writable by switching to the apache user `sudo -u apache -s /bin/bash` and running `touch /path/to/portal.log`.

Comment: touch command works fine :/

Answer (score 1):

As it can create the log file I don't think the problem is directory permissions, and setting the permission flags to world-read-and-writable-and-executable (777) makes no difference I don't it is file permissions or ownership either.

Could the be an error in how the library is being called such that it thinks there is nothing to log yet? Is this working for you in any other environment?

Also, how much should have been logged by this point? Could the library be buffering outputs for a while instead of writing every line as it comes in? Try making sure lots *should* be written to rule out this.

Comment: The log lib is working fine on my Windows development computer, I already check if it was a path problem, but it seems good to me (it creates the file...), I don't see other things to check between my environment...